# Bitcoin blockchain parser c# snippet to vb

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get this snippet to vb but keep getting errors in the ide

```
var header = new byte[8];
int index = 0;
var magic_signature = ((uint)header[index++] << 0) | ((uint)header[index++] << 8) | ((uint)header[index++] << 16) | ((uint)header[index++] << 24);
```

I tried an online coverter and got this (which produces errors)

```
Dim magic_signature = (CUInt(header(Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index), index - 1))) << 0) Or (CUInt(header(Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index), index - 1))) << 8) Or (CUInt(header(Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index), index - 1))) << 16) Or (CUInt(header(Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index), index - 1))) << 24)
```

The header variable is filled after declaration.
Could someone help me convert the above to vb.net?

**EDIT**:
Populating header via reading a stream

```
Dim header = New Byte(8) {}
If stream.Read(header, 0, 8) < 8 Then
    Throw New ApplicationException("Incomplete data.")
End If
```

Comment: Can you supply the declaration line of `header` in your converted vb.net code please?

Comment: @Codexer I personally frown on code conversion questions, but it seems people on Meta disagree :) - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54345/please-convert-my-code-to-x-questions . As the OP has already attempted code conversion (I tried it on telerik myself) with no success, I would be inclined to post an answer as the code is concise, and the Op isn't asking us to convert an entire program.

Comment: @Mike_OBrien - I've added the code to declare and populate the header.

Comment: That `Math.Max(Threading.Interlocked.Increment(index), index - 1)` silliness for `i++` is broken for when index is 0. That right there is why the translation didn't work.

Comment: @rskar agreed, I believe the translator was replacing the `Index++` portion without seeing that the addition had to be done after the evaluation. VB.net does not have an equivalent to the `++` operator so inline functions like this can not be translated by an automated tool reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike_OBrien has pointed out, VB doesn't have a built-in `++` - but we can fake one easily enough:

```
Function PostIncr(ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
    ' PostIncr(i) works like i++
    Dim x0 As Integer = x : x += 1 : Return x0
End Function
```

After that, conversion is straightforward:

```
    Dim header(7) As Byte

    ' Make believe this is a stream.Read
    Array.Copy({CByte(1), CByte(2), CByte(3), CByte(4)},
        header, 4)

    Dim index As Integer = 0
    Dim magic_signature = CUInt(header(PostIncr(index))) << 0 Or
        CUInt(header(PostIncr(index))) << 8 Or
        CUInt(header(PostIncr(index))) << 16 Or
        CUInt(header(PostIncr(index))) << 24
```

And for fun:

```
Function PreIncr(ByRef x As Integer) As Integer
    ' PreIncr(i) works like ++i
    x += 1 : Return x
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe David Wilson is on the right path but as rskar pointed out the `Index + 1` portion does not produce the same results as `index++` would in c#. The easiest way to get the behavior from c# would be to break the single command into multiple commands and store the results in temp variables, incrementing `Index` between each step and then evaluating the temp variables at the end. This would result in a lot more code however.

Ex:

```
Dim temp1 = (CUInt(header(Index)) << 0)
Index += 1
Dim temp2 = (CUInt(header(Index)) << 8)
Index += 1
Dim temp3 = (CUInt(header(Index)) << 16)
Index += 1
Dim magic_signature As UInteger = temp1 Or temp2 Or temp3 Or (CUInt(header(Index)) << 24)
```

Unfortunately to my knowledge there isn't anything in vb.net that behaves the same as the `++` operator in c#.

Comment: After seeing this answer, I would be inclined to go with it - I slightly (though importantly misunderstood)